# How to change default sql server configuration in Microsoft webmatrix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, webmatrix, web-platform-installer

I am using webmatrix ( http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ ) to install DNN (dotnetnuke). when i try to install it is asking **'sa'** password for SQL express.

I am using SQL server 2012 and when i enter 'sa' password webmatrix says "**The password for username 'sa' is invalid**".
i can connect to database using SQL server management studio with the same sa password with server name SATISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS .
I referred all microsoft documentation for solving problem but not solved.
Finally i try to install DNN using web installer 4.6( http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx ) then it shows "Database Server: .\SQLexprress" and ask for password..
Actually my database server is SATISH-PC\SQLexpress or SATISH-PC.

I searched around "%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config" to change default SQL server configuration but i am unable to find default configuration related to webmatrix.

I think this is the problem if not please let me know what the problem is.
if this is the problem please tell how to configure database server in webmatrix.

Thank you.

Comment: If it wants to logon as Sa then the Instance needs to be set to SqlServer or Mixed mode security and you need to add the login and set the privileges. By default on a sql server install, it's set to integrated only and the administrator is the windows user that installed it. ie. there is no sa user

Comment: I already set to mixed mode. I can logon on to sql server management studio with password which is set by me for sa user.
The screenshots are given below..
http://i.imgur.com/33S88bX.png
http://i.imgur.com/dY1IA2y.png

Comment: I am able to connect as sa user .

see screenshots below
 http://i.imgur.com/ReIfBJx.png
http://i.imgur.com/71iwigf.png

Comment: Never used webmatrix , make sure auditing is on, try again, have a peek in the logs files maybe that will tell you something.

Comment: Thanks @TonyHopkinson , But i am unable to find anything about SQL Server info in log files at  %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\

Comment: Sql server log files!

Comment: I am also having this problem!!!